# angular 8 reactive form with custom ng-select not touched programmatically

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-validation, angular-ngselect

I have a custom `angular reactive form` with `ng-select` in it with other components. While validating the form I added the below code

```
private validateCustForm() {
    this.validation.touchFormControls(this.appointmentForm);
    if (this.appointmentForm.invalid) {
      return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

to show the validation message when click on the submit button. It is working with all the form elements **except for the custom ng-select element**

**Is there any way to make the custom ng-select element get touched programmatically after I click on the submit button?**

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood correctly, you want to focus on some input field if your form isnt submitted.

Try for focus, available with angular material ( i guess you are using angular material here ) . It has MdInputDirective which has a focus() method. You can us ViewChildren for referencing and then pass something like below ->

```
this.inputs.find(input => !input._ngControl.valid).focus()
```

Let me know if this helps